# Substitutes for Sabra liquer

Tags: substitutions

I am making a simple torte, just eggs, walnuts and shredded coconut. After is baked and out of the oven I am to pour 1/2 cup orange juice mixed with 1/4 cup Sabra liqueur. What other liqueur can I use?

Answer (score 3):

The flavor profile of Sabra liqueur is described as [rich chocolate and orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabra_liqueur).

So if you have it, chocolate liqueur and orange liqueur would be the straightforward substitute.

If you don’t have chocolate liqueur, you could instead either add chocolate into the batter, dust with cocoa or add a chocolate glaze.

If you don’t have orange liqueur, consider orange peel either in the batter or on the cake.

If have neither and substitute both elements, you should decide whether you want the alcoholic component or not (use a fairly neutral kind in the drizzle).

As a liqueur contains sugar, you may or may not have to add some to the drizzle, depending on how much sweetness your substitutes bring.